# Help removing this stubborn bit on my model

Tags: mesh

When moving the opposite arm on this model I get this small error. I've tried getting rid of it with weight painting but it's still linked to the opposite arm. It does not show any paint in the weight paint mode. I've also tried merging as well as deleting the vertices. I am very new to this so please forgive me.

[image: Small bit I cant remove]
[Link to my blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T2caAtPauu3CrjEqN0iHKIVjnsdHWmzE/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0):

Enable the first 2 options of the *Armature* modifier, switch your object to *Edit* mode, select the vertex, open the *N panel > Item > Vertex Weights* and remove the vertex from the group called *forearm.L*:

[image]

Or, faster, you can select this vertex, shift select another that works correctly, and press on the *Copy* button:

[image]

You can also see the problem if you switch to *Weight Paint* mode and select this bone, then you can subtract with the brush:

[image]